# Spy on window function with testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to test with testcafe if a function on a window object is executed with certain parameters. Is it possible with Testcafe?

The function call looks like this:

```
window.myObject.myFunction({customObject: true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html) API to create a spy function in a window object. Please look at the following test example:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `https://cf51n.csb.app/`;

const spyOn = ClientFunction(() => {
  // Create an array where we store information about `myFunction` calls
  window.myFunctionSpyData = [];

  // Store the original `myFunction` value
  window.orirginalFunction = window.myObject.myFunction;

  
  window.myObject.myFunction = function() {
    // Save data about the current call
    window.myFunctionSpyData.push(...arguments);

    // Call the original `myFunction` value
    window.orirginalFunction(...arguments);
  }
});

const getSpyData = ClientFunction(() => {
  // Retrieve data about myFunction calls from client
  return window.myFunctionSpyData;
});

const spyOff = ClientFunction(() => {
  // Restore the original myFunction value
  window.myObject.myFunction = window.orirginalFunction;
  delete window.spyData;
});

test('New Test', async t => {
    await spyOn();

    await t.click('#btn');

    const data = await getSpyData();
    await spyOff();

    await t
        .expect(data.length).eql(2)
        .expect(data[0]).eql('1')
        .expect(data[1]).eql('2');
});
```